# If nx + ky = kx+ny, where x,y,n and m are all real numbers and x is not equal to y.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What can we say about the relationship between n and k ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : The equation is equivalent to $$nx-ny=kx-ky$$ Now, factor out $n$ and $k$

Comment: I should have noticed that rearrangement. Anyway, thank you for your answer.